# Relationship between Stack Overflow, Inc and OpenStudy

Tags: support

I just received some unsolicited email:

> A team of developers and I are working on a project to make a better Stack Overflow system called OpenStudy. Because of your previous experience on Stack Overflow, we would love for you to come beta test our new site

At first, I thought it was another initiative from Joel and Jeff.

However, the email address it was sent to was NOT one associated with my Stack Overflow accounts - I suspect they have grabbed it from my blog, which mentions Stack Overflow.

I wanted to confirm whether Stack Overflow and OpenStudy have any relationship.

Comment: Referring to the system as a "Stack Overflow" system seems like a poor way to show your superiority. It's like saying "we're making a better Google" instead of "we're making a better search engine"

Comment: uh-oh! they have cute looking blue owl mascots on the site... SO doesn't stand a chance!

Comment: Very open study - apparently you have to register to see anything.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No relationship whatsoever. Never heard of them.

Oh, and a system *better* than Stack Overflow? Is that even possible? I am not so sure.. :)

Comment: ... if you're going to write -1, then you better follow it up with an actual downvote

Comment: *anything* is possible... **anything**!